# Filter unique array values from three fields

Tags: php, arrays

How to filter the unique array values of

- Primary Contact Email
- Preferred Telephone
- First Name

I'm using

```
array_unique($data, SORT_REGULAR);
```

but its checking all the values. How can I filter three fields? Sample data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [First Name] => xyz
            [Last Name] => abc
            [Primary Contact Email] => xyz@hotmail.com
            [Preferred Telephone] => 1-123-000-123
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [First Name] => xyz
            [Last Name] => abc
            [Primary Contact Email] => xyz@hotmail.com
            [Preferred Telephone] => 1-123-000-123
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [First Name] => dss
            [Last Name] => sddfs
            [Primary Contact Email] => dss@hotmail.com
            [Preferred Telephone] => 1-553-000-123
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [First Name] => dss
            [Last Name] => sds
            [Primary Contact Email] => dss@hotmail.com
            [Preferred Telephone] => 1-444-000-123
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [First Name] => dss
            [Last Name] => sds
            [Primary Contact Email] => dss@hotmail.com
            [Preferred Telephone] => 1-553-000-123
        )
)
```

target data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [First Name] => xyz
            [Last Name] => abc
            [Primary Contact Email] => xyz@hotmail.com
            [Preferred Telephone] => 1-123-000-123
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [First Name] => dss
            [Last Name] => sddfs
            [Primary Contact Email] => dss@hotmail.com
            [Preferred Telephone] => 1-553-000-123
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [First Name] => dss
            [Last Name] => sds
            [Primary Contact Email] => dss@hotmail.com
            [Preferred Telephone] => 1-444-000-123
        )
)
```

Comment: you can reindex the array with the combined values of the three fields you want. However, it is unclear what should happen, when a duplicate is found. Which of the entries should remain? In your example, passport is different. Which of the two should end up in the reindexed array?

Comment: I wrote up a solution but it's unclear what you want the final result to look like. Are you looking for an array of emails, an array of names...?  Or do you want something in the same shape as the input, but filter out any element that has a non-unique name, email or phone

Comment: Please provide the desired output for your example. Thanks.

Comment: You must use array_unique or u can do it in looop?

Comment: It should return skip $data[0] as three fields are matched with same value. i.e email, firstname and tel

Comment: @user6606700 can you please make up your mind what you want. You [commented below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450430/array-unique-value-that-check-three-fields#comment64306268_38450565) that it should keep $data[0] and $data[1]. Now you say it should "return skip $data[0]" (whatever that means). You are not making any sense.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself and I will lose interest soon I'm sorry to say. If you want us to help, help us by giving us a bigger input dataset and the expected output.

Comment: OK i'm beginning to understand. Does the comparison ignore the last name?

Comment: yes correct it doesn't matter what ever in last name or any fields

Comment: should the comparison be case-sensitive?  Meaning is "james" different from "JAMES"?

Comment: No case-sensitive no matter

Comment: ok I've posted a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. The input array is called `$inputs`. To get it to work with your code, you'll need to change the array keys. Here I use `first`, `mail`, and `phone` to be brief. Your keys are `First Name`, `Primary Contact Email`, and `Preferred Telephone`

```
$inputs = [...];// your starting data
$results = []; // Starts empty; will be filled with the output

foreach($inputs as $input){
    $isDuplicate = false;
    foreach($results as $result){
        if(
            strtolower($input['first'])===strtolower($result['first']) &&
            strtolower($input['mail'])===strtolower($result['mail']) &&
            $input['phone']===$result['phone']
        ){
            //a duplicate was found in results
            $isDuplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //if no duplicate was found, add this input to results.
    if(!$isDuplicate) $results[]=$input;
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/35f26c3a80a6aa40c484f0e6f95f669dcfbcbcf9)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an anonymous function within `array_filter` to filter out identical data. Here's how:

```
        <?php

            $arrTmp         = array();
            $arrContactData = array(
                array(
                    "First Name"            => "xyz",
                    "Last Name"             => "abc",
                    "Primary Contact Email" => "xyz@hotmail.com",
                    "Preferred Telephone"   => "1-123-000-123",
                ),
                array(
                    "First Name"            => "xyz",
                    "Last Name"             => "differentLastName",
                    "Primary Contact Email" => "xyz@hotmail.com",
                    "Preferred Telephone"   => "1-123-000-123",
                ),
                array(
                    "First Name"            => "xyz",
                    "Last Name"             => "abc",
                    "Primary Contact Email" => "xyz@hotmail.com",
                    "Preferred Telephone"   => "1-123-000-123",
                ),
                array(
                    "First Name"            => "dss",
                    "Last Name"             => "sds",
                    "Primary Contact Email" => "dss@hotmail.com",
                    "Preferred Telephone"   => "1-444-000-123",
                ),
                array(
                    "First Name"            => "dss",
                    "Last Name"             => "sds",
                    "Primary Contact Email" => "dss@hotmail.com",
                    "Preferred Telephone"   => "1-553-000-123",
                ),
                array(
                    "First Name"            => "dss",
                    "Last Name"             => "sds",
                    "Primary Contact Email" => "dss@hotmail.com",
                    "Preferred Telephone"   => "1-553-000-123",
                ),
            );

            $arrFiltered = array_filter($arrContactData, function ($data){
                global $arrTmp;
                if(is_array($data)) {

                    if (!in_array($data, $arrTmp)) {
                        foreach($arrTmp as $arr){
                            if( strtolower($arr['Last Name'])               != strtolower($data['Last Name']) &&
                                strtolower($arr['First Name'])              == strtolower($data['First Name']) &&
                                strtolower($arr['Primary Contact Email'])   == strtolower($data['Primary Contact Email']) &&
                                strtolower($arr['Preferred Telephone'])     == strtolower($data['Preferred Telephone'])){
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                        $arrTmp[] = $data;
                        return $data;
                    }               
                }
                return null;
            });

            var_dump($arrFiltered);
            // PRODUCES::
            array (size=3)
              0 => 
                array (size=4)
                  'First Name' => string 'xyz' (length=3)
                  'Last Name' => string 'abc' (length=3)
                  'Primary Contact Email' => string 'xyz@hotmail.com' (length=15)
                  'Preferred Telephone' => string '1-123-000-123' (length=13)
              2 => 
                array (size=4)
                  'First Name' => string 'dss' (length=3)
                  'Last Name' => string 'sds' (length=3)
                  'Primary Contact Email' => string 'dss@hotmail.com' (length=15)
                  'Preferred Telephone' => string '1-444-000-123' (length=13)
              3 => 
                array (size=4)
                  'First Name' => string 'dss' (length=3)
                  'Last Name' => string 'sds' (length=3)
                  'Primary Contact Email' => string 'dss@hotmail.com' (length=15)
                  'Preferred Telephone' => string '1-553-000-123' (length=13)
```

Test it out yourself [here](https://eval.in/607561).

Comment: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Comment: @ user6606700  Probably the main array contains not only arrays but null data or other datatypes. Post has been updated to take that into account. Try again (if you will)... Test it out here: https://eval.in/607561

Comment: same response in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Comment: @user6606700  another clause has now been added `&& !empty($data)` to the `if(in_array())` clause... you may want to give it another shot...

Comment: This code will not meet the OP's requirements. With this code, if two elements have the same first name, email and phone, but different last names they will be recorded as different elements. But the OP has stated that last names should be ignored, so the right result would be that those two elements are duplicate.  In addition, the OP has stated that the comparison should not be case sensitive. With this solution, the first names `xyz` and `XYZ` will be treated as different names

Comment: Hi @Poiz. The last 2 sentences of my comment still apply